# How open balls under uniform topology will look in $\Bbb R^{n}$

Tags: general-topology

I was trying to figure out how open ball of radius $a$ under uniform metric will look in $\Bbb R^{n}$ around the origin. So I started with $\Bbb R^{2}$ first.

I conclude that if $a>1$, the open ball will be the entire plane and if $a \leq 1$, metric will behave same as that of square metric i.e. open balls will be open squares(Am I correct?). So can I just generalise this to any $n>1$. Means if $a>1$, open ball will be whole space and if $a\leq 1$, it is same as square metric i.e. open balls will look like open multidimensional cuboids(for $n= 3$, they are cuboids but I don't know what to call for $n>3$, so I used word multidimensional cuboids). Am I thinking correct? If not how this open balls will look around origin?

(I feel I am going wrong somewhere because if this is the structure of open balls under uniform topology, my geometric thinking is saying that this will make box topology and uniform topology equivalent but as we know the box is finer than uniform, so I think I am missing something)

Can someone please clarify things in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While box topology is strictly finer than the uniform topology for the infinite product $\mathbb R^J$ (consider the box neighboorhood $\Pi_1^{\infty}(0,1)=(0,1)\times(0,1)...$ Notice $x=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{n},...)\in\Pi_1^{\infty}(0,1)$, though it doesn't contain an $\epsilon$-neighboorhood of $x$ in the uniform topology), it's equivalent to the uniform topology for $\mathbb R^n$ (as sup$_{1\leq k\leq n}|x_k-y_k|$ reduces to max$_{1\leq k\leq n}|x_k-y_k|$).

Comment: are my pictures of open balls correct? And I also have one query, in infinite product can you tell me one basic open set of box topology centred at origin for which I can't find a basic open set of uniform topology which fits inside it.

Comment: How single point (0,0,...) is open in box?Basic open set have form (a,b)*(c,d)*.......?Sorry but can u bit elaborate?

Comment: Thanks Sir.....

Comment: @Believer Sorry. I made a mistake. Now corrected. I must be too tired. (You are right, $(0,0,...,)$ is not open in the box topology)

Comment: Ok..no problem..